# Create multiple markers on a map with a Firestore database

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-cloud-firestore

I want to show multiple markers based on querying by type on a Google map and I am using Firestore to store my data. I am bit confused and lost trying to create markers with my Firestore database in Android. I don´t know how to correctly connect a default marker creation to the query function from Firebase.

I stored information about some greenery in Sydney within four field types. I have three strings (name, type and info) and one geopoint type with the coordinates. My database structure looks like this:

[image]

I found tutorials that shows how to load string values from a Firestore database and to load them into your app but I found no beginner-friendly explanation for loading geographical information on a map. I tried to modify the basic code to create a marker on Google Developers but apparently nothing came out of it. So there is not a lot of code I have.

```
private GoogleMap mMap; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference citiesRef = db.collection("sydney_nature");
Query query = citiesRef.whereEqualTo("type", "Park");

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in 
    Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    mMap.animateCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo( 10.0f ) );
     }
```

I hope to create markers which by click open up a info box that shows the name of the place. Currently I get nothing because I am not able to perform the correct query. @Alex Mamo my current errors:[image]

Comment: Please add your database structure to see how you store the GeoPoint in your document.

Comment: @AlexMamo Thank you, i updated my post!

Comment: So basically you want to add the `geo` under `points_au (collction) -> Park (document)` to the map, right?

Comment: @Alex Mamo Yes, correct!

Comment: Ok, I'll write you an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display the `geo` under `points_au (collction) -> Park (document)` on the map, please use the following lines of code:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference pointsRef = rootRef.collection("points_au");
DocumentReference parkRef = pointsRef.document("Park");
parkRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document.exists()) {
                GeoPoint geo = document.getGeoPoint("geo");
                String name = document.getString("name");
                double lat = geo.getLatitude();
                double lng = geo.getLongitude();
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(name));
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The result will be a marker that is added on the map which has the title of `Royal Botanic Gardens`.

Comment: Did you try to run the code? Unfortunately i get several errors. I can post the rest of my code here.

Comment: Yes, is tested. What are the errors? Paste them here.

Comment: error: <identifier> expected (after get() method) 
error: ';' expected (after get()method)
error: illegal start of type (after first <DocumentSnapshot>)
error: '(' expected (behind first DocumentSnapshot)
error: ';' expected (behind public void onComplete)
error: ';' expected (behind first "task")
error: illegal start of type (after the last curly bracket)

Also, "get" and "task" cannot be resolved. It says "annotations not allowed here" at @NonNull. Hope this helps.

Comment: Show me a screenshot of your error, to see it more clearly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186221/discussion-between-dee-jott-and-alex-mamo).